# Run python script multiple times as a background process with different configuration

Tags: python, linux

I used php to run python script on Linux via web after running and I get process ID

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <?php
      echo 'Starting the mapping process';
      echo exec('nohup python cloudemir.py '.$_GET[message].' > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $! &');
     ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

which is then used to kill the process when I don't need it which works fine

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <?php
        $pid=$_GET['pid'];
        echo exec("kill -9 $pid");
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

The python script I used is just publishing one message via MQTT every second. The problem is that I can't change the message content.

If the message is Hi, and I run this process, it says "Hi", "Hi"... every second. If I change python script message to Hi2, and run it again I get new process id and new message is Hi2 every second and there is no Hi message any more.

I need it to run separately and to get both messages, and when needed to kill one of them. I need it to be able to run unlimited number of instances of that python sctipt with different configuiration, I don't need to build new scripts.

domain/run.php?message=Hi

domain/run.php?message=Hi2

This should print Hi, Hi2, Hi, Hi2

domain/run.php?message=Hi

domain/run.php?message=Hi2

domain/run.php?message=Hi3

This should print Hi, Hi2, Hi3, Hi, Hi2, Hi3

In both cases it prints only last message

I even tried the same without php, but calling the script from another python script with

```
proc = subprocess.Popen("nohup python cloudemir.py "+content+" > /dev/null 2>&1 &", shell=True)
```

But it remains the same, last call overwrites the previous

Comment: Are you saying that you want your python script to remember all the messages it has received until it is killed?

Comment: I guess what I am asking is how do you know, how many messages a python instance will handle?
domain/run.php?message=Hi
domain/run.php?message=Hi2 maybe you need a domain/run.php?clear_state=True or something like that?

Comment: I suppose that because I am running the script in the backgound, each time I run it it is new instance and runs separately. Is that possible?

Comment: yes exec will return a new instance, you could store the contents in a file somewhere and read that file... but that would give all the messages unless you add in some options to the python script to clear that file.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `sys.argv`. As an example of the file `cloudemir.py`:

```py
import sys

print(sys.argv[0])
```

And then you can call it with:

```
python cloudemir.py Hi # First time
python cloudemir.py Hi2 # Second time
```

This way the name after `cloudemir.py` will be inputed as a param to the python program.

Comment: It is good solution for improvement, but still only one message is printed. And the argv[0] printed the name of the program, and agr[1] printed the message. I need both messages runing, not one to replace another.